# How to detect unreleased lock in multi-task C project using static analysis tools?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, static-analysis

Is there any way, using static analysis tools(I'm using Codesonar now), to detect unreleased lock problems (something like unreleased semaphores) in the following program?（The comment part marked by arrows）

The project is a multi-task system using Round-robin scheduling, where `new_request()` is an interrupt task comes randomly and `send_buffer()` is another period task.

In real case, `get_buffer()` and `send_buffer()` are various types of wrappers, which contains many call layers until actual lock/unlock process. So I can't simply specify `get_buffer()` as `lock function` in settings of static analysis tool.

```cpp
int bufferSize = 0;     // say max size is 5

// random task
void new_request()
{
    int bufferNo = get_buffer();    // wrapper

    if (bufferNo == -1)
    {
        return;    // buffer is full
    }   

    if (check_something() == OK)
    {
        add_to_sendlist(bufferNo);  // for asynchronous process of send_buffer()
    }
    else    // bad request
    {
        // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
        // There should be clear_buffer placed here
        // but forgotten. Eventually the buffer will be
        // full and won't be cleared since 5th bad request comes.
        // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

        do_nothing();
        // clear_buffer(bufferNo);
    }
}

int get_buffer()
{
    if(bufferSize < 5)
    {
        bufferSize++;
        return bufferSize;
    }
    else
    {
        wait_until_empty(); // wait until someone is sent by send_buffer()
        return -1;
    }

}

// clear specifiled one in buffer
void clear_buffer(int bufferNo) 
{
    delete(bufferNo)
    bufferSize--;
    
}
```

```
// period task
void send_buffer()
{
    int sent = send_1st_stuff_in_list();
    clear_buffer(sent);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need this?  I ask because, after a lot of years writing multithreaded apps, I have not yet seen such an issue that does not result in either an obvious loop, lockup, deadlock or an obvious segfault/AV catastrophe during testing  Maybe it's just luck and I should buy lottery tickets:)

Comment: Note that I'm not saying that I don't get those problems, merely that they are easily found and fixed:)

Comment: This is an old code, where we recently found that attackers can use this bug, sending maliciously modified bad request to make send_buffer stop work. And I want to find all similar bugs using static analysis, if possible.

Comment: Sounds grim.  You may have to fix a lot more than locking:((

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yoyozi - Fair disclosure: I'm an engineer at GrammaTech who works on CodeSonar.

First some general things. The relevant parts of the manual for this are on the page: codesonar/doc/html/C_Module/LibraryModels/ConcurrencyModelsLocks.html. Especially the bottom of the page on Resolving Lock Operation Identification Problems.

Based on your comments, I think you have already read this, since you address setting the names in the configuration settings.

So then the question is how many different wrappers do you have? If it is only a few, then the settings in the configuration file are the way to go. If there are many, that gets tedious. And if there are very many it becomes practically impossible.

So knowing some estimate for how many wrapper sets you have would help.

Even with the wrappers accounted for, it may be that the deadlock and race detectors aren't quite what you need for your problem.

If I understand your issue correctly, you have a queue with limited space, and by accident malformed items don't get cleaned out of the queue, and so the queue gets full and that stalls all processing. While you may have multiple threads involved in this implementation, the issue itself would still be a problem in a basically serial setting.

The best way to work with an issue like this is to try and make a simpler example that displays the same core problem. If you can do this in a way that can be shared with GrammaTech, we can work with you on ways to adjust settings or maybe provide hints to the analysis so it can find this issue.

If you would like to talk about this in more detail, and with prodetction against public disclosure of your code, please contact us at support_at_grammatech_dot_com, where the *at* and *dot* should be replaced as needed to make a well formed email address.